# What's the layout files sequence in Yii?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am new with Yii and recently I have been able to manage to update some layout files and I think I understand what I did. I put my layout files in `/protected/modules/admin/views/layouts` ("admin" is the name of my module) and made some changes in appropriate controllers (mostly I have changed the `public $layout` variabe to something like `/layouts/column2`. It worked.

Today I have installed new theme and my question now is: what is the order in which Yii goes through the directory structure and looks for the layouts? I have found somewhere that I need to create the directory called `layouts` under the `/themes/bootstrap/views` ("bootstrap" is the name of my theme). I have done that but these layouts are not included. How can I get my `/themes/bootstrap/views/` layouts included instead of the module ones? And the last but not least - what is the best approach to theme an application? I would love to have all formatting in one place, ideally the theme folder. I believe that's doable but I think I am missing some good advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a starting point, [look over the source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/web/CController.php#L594).

Answer (score 0):

On `CController::render()` yii applies layout. 
If  in render function you set false - then will be no layout searched, 
otherwise yii watch for `public $layout` in CController (means if its set in your controller this layout will be used). 
If `public $layout` in CController not set it will use `CWebApplication::layout`, which you can change in your config.

For themes please read this guide http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/topics.theming